# Efficient way to store and retrieve timestamped data from multiple sensors

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am working on a project where I'm collecting data from four sensors and currently saving into a nested dictionary as `{'sensor1': {'timestamp': 'data', ...}, 'sensor2': {'timestamp': 'data', ...}, ...}`. The sensors provide data at about 500 samples a second. `timestamp` is a 4-byte data representing the running time of the Arduino in microseconds. `data` is either 2 or 4 bytes depending on the sensor.

What would be the most efficient way to store the data and retrieve the data from a  sensor between two specified time values?

Comment: efficient would be using a different datastructure. However, just iterate through the dict, and check timestamps for all sensors.

Comment: What data structure would you recommend?

Comment: @PrateekDhanuka, *between two given time values.* - post a testable time values, are those datetime-strings?

Comment: This seems like tabular data to me, and so i'd personally prefer a pandas dataframe for this. However, it really depends on how many sensors you really have, and whether it's difficult to iterate through them all or not.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest The values will be generated dynamically as the program executes. As the program processes data from sensor 1, it requires samples at specific times relative to the time from sensor 2. No, they are not DateTime strings. They are 4 bytes of data which represent the running time of the Arduino in microseconds

Comment: @ParitoshSingh There are 4 sensors, the sensors generate data at about 500 samples a second. 2 of the sensors give 2 bytes of data, the other two give 4 bytes of data and the timestamp is always 4 bytes

Comment: You could get a very compact Python code with Pandas: `pd.DataFrame(your_dict)[timestamp_min:timestamp_max]`.

Comment: On Arduino, do you use callbacks for each sensor or do you record data sequentially inside loop()? If the latter, then you should have the same number of records for each sensor, meaning a pandas.DataFrame object will do just fine and you can store separate time axes for each sensor.

Comment: What do you mean by separate time axes for each sensor? I was thinking of using it with time being the index and the value for the other sensors being NaN.